# How to select a submit button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 in a jsp and I have a function that filters out a select element on a change event, which works fine.  I also want to filter out a save button as well in the same function.

It seemed difficult to try and pinpoint the buttons as there are more than one, so I opted for a class to distinguish them.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
        $(':input:not("select")').change(function(){
            $(':input:submit:not(".saveButton")'){
                // Do something here.
            }
        }); ...
```

Here are the buttons. It's Struts2 tags:

```
<td>
    <s:submit action="<actionName>"  cssClass="saveButton" value="Save" />
</td>                   
<td>
    <s:submit  action="<anotherActionName>" value="Cancel" />
</td>
```

but when I run this it's not working at all with the extra input.  I'm not sure if this is correct syntax or if it's the best approach either?  Any ideas on this?

This is what I found that worked, based on the answer below:

```
$(function(){

$(':input:not("select")').change(function(){
            if($(':submit:not(".saveButton")')) { ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems awkward having many submit buttons.

Comment: Well it's a save and cancel, just two actually.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard Why don't you just use IDs then or something? It would be easier than this... or even classes maybe? So you can do `$('.buttons_class:not(".saveButton")')` or something. You're making it too hard for just two buttons.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard Can we see the markup for your buttons?

Comment: It's SO not clear from your question what you're actually trying to do.  Please post your HTML, and please explain *the intended behavior* - saying "it's not working at all" doesn't provide us with the information we need to get it working *correctly*.

Comment: With the second line for the input, the top input stops working for some reason.  When I take out the second line it correctly filters out the select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  $(function(){
    $(':input:not("select")').change(function(){
        $('.cancelButton').change(function(){
            // Do something here.
        });
    });
```

UPDATED: you were making life too complicated, just select the cancel button if there are only two of them.

Comment: What is `$('.cancelButton'){}`? And where does `$(function(){` get closed?

Comment: Sometimes I do that!  I was wanting to make it class specific to use on other pages as they are form based and all will have save buttons and selects.

Comment: KISS - it's better to sacrifice a wee bit of re-use in favour of legible and maintainable code.

Comment: I'll update the answer in a bit when I figure out the selector you were trying to build - won't sleep otherwise ;)

Comment: I left out the rest of the code.  I put ... in to indicate that now.  Thanks Jonathan!